# How to update Remote Host Using Ansible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible

I each of my remote servers I want to run the equivalent of:

```sh
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Before running anything, when I login in the Server I get the following messages:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.10 (GNU/Linux 4.18.0-10-generic x86_64)
...

...
132 packages can be updated.
79 updates are security updates.
```

Then, I run the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: myserver
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:

    - name: "Update packages"
      apt:
        update_cache: yes # apt-get update
        upgrade: full

    - name: "Update dist"
      apt:
         upgrade: dist

    - name: UpdateRaw
      shell: apt-get update -y
    - name: UpgradeRaw
      shell: apt-get upgrade -y
    - name: DistUpgradeRaw
      shell: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

using the command

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts update.yml --check
```

But when I go back to server I still see the same message:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.10 (GNU/Linux 4.18.0-10-generic x86_64)
...

...
132 packages can be updated.
79 updates are security updates.
```

How do I update my server using ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The --check option executes ansible in dry run mode. You need to remove the --check flag, in order to actually execute the play on the remote hosts. 
The correct command is:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts update.yml
```

Please see below link

[Ansible Dry Run](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_checkmode.html)